# acces to data on the navigateur tabellete safari

Tags: sqlite, jboss, safari, offline, web-sql

I have a web application that uses the server jboss and I want access to this application by the browser(safari) of my tablet air 2.
I want to know how I can launch my application on the safari browser of my tablet or mobile (IOS) locally without going through a connection to a server.
I am waiting your answer.

Comment: Please provide your existing code so that someone can help you better. Also show any errors. Here is how to ask a question in stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Thanks.

Comment: i just want an idea i don't have a problem in code